# Cannot export QNN brevitas to ONNX

Tags: python, machine-learning, pytorch, fpga, onnx

I have trained my model as QNN with brevitas. Basically my input shape is:

> torch.Size([1, 3, 1024])

I have exported the .pt extended file. As I try my model and generate a confusion matrix I was able to observe everything that I want.
So I believe that there is no problem about the model.

On the other hand as I try to export the .onnx file to implement this brevitas trained model on FINN, I wrote the code given below:

```
from brevitas.export import FINNManager
FINNManager.export(my_model, input_shape=(1, 3, 1024), export_path='myfinnmodel.onnx')
```

But as I do that I get the error as:

> torch.onnx.export(module, input_t, export_target, **kwargs)
>
> TypeError: export() got an unexpected keyword argument
> 'enable_onnx_checker'

I do not think this is related with the version. But if you want me to be sure about the version, I can check these too.

If you can help me I will be really appreciated.
Sincerely;

Answer (score 0):

The problem is related to pytorch version > 1.10. Where "enable_onnx_checker" is no more a parameter of torch.onnx.export function.

This is the official solution from the repository.
https://github.com/Xilinx/brevitas/pull/408/files

The fix is not yet release. Is in dev branch.
You need to compile brevitas by yourself or simply change the code in brevitas/export/onnx/manager.py following official solution.

After that i am able to get onnx converted model.